# Python - parsing through PDFs exporting text and count of keyword - issue counting keywords in list, counting each page instead

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, text, pypdf

I am trying to create a program that loops through a folder of PDFs, extracts the text, and counts the occurrences of "professor frank." I can get the looping and text extraction to work fine, but only sort of the keyword count. My code is counting each page which is fine, but when I export it via Pandas, it's just exporting the entire list, each with a count per page.  I figured I could just run a Sum command and count the totals for each PDF, but I'm missing something. For simplicity, I'm just using two PDFs here.  Bottom line, I want one simple count of the frequency that "professor frank" appears in each PDF file and I'm missing something here, likely with how I'm looping.

My Current Output (using a pipe delimiter) - both with my current count output and desired:

**TEXT**               | **FILE_LOCATION**     | **CURRENT_FRANK_COUNT** | **DESIRED_FRANK_COUNT**
 
This is a paper.       | C:\PDF\Test\file1.pdf | 1,2,0,0,0,1,2,1 | 6 
This is the 2nd paper. | C:\PDF\Test\file2.pdf | 1,0,0,0,0,2,1,1 | 5

```
import re
import PyPDF2
import os, sys
import pandas as pd

path = r"C:\PDF\Test"
files = []

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r,file))

out = []

for file in files:

    with open(file,'rb') as pdf_file:

        read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        alltext = []
        allfrankcount = []

        for page_number in range(number_of_pages):  
            page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)           
            page_content = page.extractText().encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
            page_content = str(page_content)
            xx = page_content.split('\\n')
            xx = " ".join(xx)
            xx = str(xx)
            alltext.append(xx)
            s = xx.lower()
            frank_count = len(re.findall(r'(?=professor frank)', s))
            allfrankcount.append(frank_count)

        for a in allfrankcount: #I know this doesn't work, but I want to demonstrate that I tried
            a = int(a) # ditto
            papertotal = sum(a)# ditto

        data = {'text': alltext, 'file': file, 'frank_count': allfrankcount}

        out.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(out)
df.to_excel('frankoutput.xlsx')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: allfrankcount = [] this line should be above the for loop

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I gave that a try and it just give me the list of counted keywords of the file1.pdf.  Unfortunately, it also still gave me a list of numbers in the output instead of a single count.

Comment: I'm trying to understand, you want sum appearence of "professor frank", in each pdf? than why the allfrankcount list for? do sum = 0, sum+= frank_count for each pdf

Comment: Yep, my problem is that it's giving me a count output for each page as a list, rather than a single count of all pages within a PDF.  I'll try that.